# How to use data members in action

Tags: jquery

I have defined a number of data members as follows:

```
    $("#slider").data("maxi", 3);
    $("#sliderb").data("maxi", 3);
    $("#sliderc").data("maxi", 4);
    $("#sliderd").data("maxi", 2);
    $("#slidere").data("maxi", 2);
    $("#sliderf").data("maxi", 1);
```

I would like to use these in an action applied to these slider selectors:

```
    $("#slider, #sliderb, #sliderc, #sliderd, #slidere, #sliderf").slider({ 

        var maxi = $(this).data('maxi');

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: maxi,
        step: 1,
        // etc...
```

However, I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = " on the line with `var maxi`.

Answer (score 1):

```
maxi: $(this).data('maxi'),
```

You're in an Object Literal, so you need `:` and `,` not `=`  and `;`

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the syntax error, but for some reason my data members are not being applied. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a variable within an object definition which is a syntax error. For what you want to do you'll have to loop through all your elements and initialize the slider with each elements data attribute:

```
$("#slider, #sliderb, #sliderc, #sliderd, #slidere, #sliderf").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: $(this).data('maxi'),
        step: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the syntax error, but for some reason my data  members are not being applied. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You could console.log($(this).data('maxi')) to see what it returns.